# How to connect on edge to the left-side-mid-height of a vertex

Tags: mxgraph

```
var vertex = graph.createVertex(null, null, value, x, y, width, height, style);
cell = graph.addCell(vertex, null);

edge = graph.createEdge(null, null, '', parent, cell, graph.createCurrentEdgeStyle());
edge = graph.addEdge(edge, null, parent, cell);
```

How can I tell this `edge` to be connected to the `left-side-mid-height` of target cell?
`parent` and `cell` are `vertex`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , finally found my own answer , just had to add a style to the edge creation

`exitX=1;exitY=0.5;exitPerimeter=1;entryX=0;entryY=0.5;entryPerimeter=1;`

this style will force the edge to exit from source's right-mid and enter target's left-mid section.